# WebViewClient onBackPressed

Tags: android

I have a webview component and would like to implement back button.

However, in this url https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient I do not see onBackPressed

Has it been deprecated?

How to implement something like this

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed(){
 
  if (webView.canGoBack()) 
    webView.goBack();
 else 
    super.onBackPressed(); <--
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, [`onBackPressed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()) is one of Activity's methods and not deprecated.